# Why does "get gerund" work with some verbs but not with all?

Tags: construction

I have noticed that "get gerund" works with some verbs:

> I have to get going.
>
> I have to get working on it.
>
> He got thinking about it.

These are not correct

> He got cleaning the house.
>
> He got climbing the ladder.

Why is it so? How can I know which ones are applicable?

Comment: Your sentences are arbitrarily chosen, and don't meaningfully reflect acceptable / unacceptable usages. For example, suppose Jack fell down the well. Jill might lower a ladder and shout down to him *You need to **get climbing the ladder** before you pass out from breathing the noxious air down there!*

Comment: The lat two sentences sound unusual to me, too, but apparently they are used by native English speakers. If you want to claim that they are "not correct", then you should provide some support for that statement. (For example, did a grammar book say so?)

Comment: @MarcInManhattan It is not that the last two "are used by English speakers"|. That's not how language works. The last two use a colloquialism which this OP may not be aware of.

Comment: @Lambie OK, then I amend it to: ". . . but apparently they are used by some native English speakers colloquially." (I specify "some" because I'm a native English speaker but wouldn't say those sentences.)

Comment: @MarcInManhattan You still do not understand what I am saying. These are not fixed expressions. It is the use specifically of get + gerund OR get + to+ gerund.

Comment: @Lambie Yes, I understand that that is what you're claiming. I've understood that since your first comment yesterday.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know of any rule  on this, it is simply accepted as natural  for some cases and not others. I fear one must simply learn what verbs can be used in this way.

I would class the "-ing" forms used in this way as present participles, not gerunds, because they are functioning as verbs, not nouns. The form is the same, the meaning is not.

One can always use "started" or "began" or "commenced" in place of this use of "got".

By the way, I would question "got thinking", it doesn't seem very natural to me.

Comment: Check this out https://youglish.com/pronounce/%22got%20thinking%22/english?

Comment: I find _got thinking_ OK. Perhaps only in BrE?

Comment: @user1425 That shows that someone uses "got thinking" enough to put its pronunciation on the net. [This Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=got+thinking%2Cbeen+thinking&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgot%20thinking%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeen%20thinking%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cgot%20thinking%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeen%20thinking%3B%2Cc0) shows it is used, but quite rarely, in the Google corpus.

Comment: *when he got **to** thinking [about something]* is fine, but [Ngrams not found: ***when he got thinking...***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=when+he+got+thinking%2Cwhen+he+got+to+thinking&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhen%20he%20got%20to%20thinking%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 2):

get means a number of things, on its own and with a gerund. One of its meanings is to begin.

"**get doing** something" is colloquial speech in AmE, anyway and is the same as:
"**get to doing** something". *He got to cleaning the steps and forgot his worries*.
*get to doing something* is a higher register and not as colloquial, regional or dialectal.

He *got cleaning* the steps. means: He **began to** clean the steps.

*get going* actually means: start going or more idiomatic: start to go somewhere, leave a place
*get working* on it means: start working on it
get moving: start moving
*He got moving on the project yesterday.*

Generally, therefore get + (to) gerund generally means to begin or start something. That is what seems to govern it. So, if it fits with the idea of beginning or starting, it might very well work.

Comment: "If it fits with the idea of beginning or starting, it might very well work." -> Are you suggesting that OP's last two example sentences are correct?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Yes, they are. I already explained that get + gerund is colloquial. I never *get* why people repose the question I have already answered.

Comment: @Lambie I for one find "got cleaning" and "got climbing" not merely colloquial, but not natural. Perhaps others disagree.

Comment: The priestess prayed quietly in the doorway and Tavera forced a smile as she got working on the hinge. She heard a distinct “clink” as the lock was picked. It popped open but wouldn't budge. Tavera wrapped her hand around it, ...https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Valley_of_Ten_Crescents_Box_Set_Book/UXjaAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22She+got+working+on+the%22&pg=PT417&printsec=frontcover

Comment: I asked because those sentences seem fairly unusual to me. (I just checked Google ngrams, which indicates that "he climbed" and "he worked" are on the same order of magnitude, while "he got climbing" isn't anywhere near "he got working"--in fact, Google couldn't even find any such uses!)

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Speakers internalize language. And not everything can be googled. I really do not care what google can find. I know that southerners, for example, say things like that.

Comment: @Lambie Got it. It may only be rare where I live.

Comment: FOUND INSIDE
I thought you were doing your banking online.” Frances looked over and shook her head. “No, I can't keep up with all those passwords, so I'm doing them by paper.” “Well, you better get doing them, then. They've been there awhile. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22You+better+get+doing%22&biw=1319&bih=607&tbm=bks&ei=8CEWY675G6jMptQPt8GEsAM&ved=0ahUKEwiusf26h_75AhUopokEHbcgATYQ4dUDCAo&uact=5&oq=%22You+better+get+doing%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEAMyBQghEKsCMgUIIRCrAlD3BVjTC2D5DWgAcAB4AYABN4gB6QGSAQE2mAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-books

Comment: @MarcInManhattan You have not understood me. Get + (to) gerund is used in colloquial speech to mean "begin to do something". A father could say to a son: You better get climbing that tree if you want to, 'cause we're leaving in one h our.

Comment: @Lambie I entirely agree with you about the meaning of that construction; I only find that it is more idiomatic in some situations than in others. (E.g.: "I have to ascend 1000 steps for my exercsie routine." "Well, then, you better get climbing!" <- Totally fine. "He got climbing the ladder." <- Sounds awkward to me.)

Comment: He got climbing the ladder to fix the roof way after our Pappy told 'em to.